# The same connection succeed and fails in different .net solutions

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I have two .net solutions. 
They both have this code:

```
var connectionString = "Server = ServerName; Database = DatabaseName; Trusted_Connection=True;"
var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

connection.Open();
connection.Close();
```

And they both use complitely the same connectionString. And they connect to MSSQL Server;

And in the first solution `connection.Open()` succeeded and in the second one it failed.
Error message : Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

And every time I create new solution it fails. So this connection only works in one specific solution. And also, my teammates tested this and didn't have such issues. 
Can you help with hints why it can be so?

Comment: What exception is thrown

Comment: If you don't provide the error message, how do you expect us to help you ?

Comment: All these different .net solutions run on your computer right?

Comment: what are the types of the applications/solutions.

Trusted_Connection will use the current user context I believe, which would be the logged in user for desktop app, but might be a different accout (network service, IIS user) for a web application

Comment: Is one a of the solutions executed via the IIS and the other one not? That would indicate that different users are used to connect and that one of them does not have the permission to connect.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add message. Updated.

Comment: All solutions are on my pc. All are console applications. It is just sql server and .net solution.

Comment: Founded out the problem. My solution was created on the another network machine. Sorry for your disturbance :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for disturbing you. My problem was my inattentiveness. I created soluiton on another network machine.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your SQL server has the TCP/IP protocol enabled and if it is using dynamic ports, ensure that the SQL Browser service is running.

Make sure that any firewall software (windows firewall etc.) has an exception added for the particular exe (the sqlservr.exe file gets copied into the instance folder, which will be in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\{instance name}\MSSQL\Binn`, where instance name might look something like `MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS`) or TCP port 1433 or UDP port 1434 (TCP 1433 for the SQL service itself assuming standard settings, UPD 1434 for the SQL Browser Service).

Check that the user account used to access the server (it should also have sufficient permissions and the login should be enabled), in this case it will be whatever windows account you are logged in as or whatever account your IIS application pool is running as because you are using `Trusted_Connection=True`.

Also check that you have an up-to-date SQL Client on your machine, you can get the latest version for windows [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff658532.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Open Sql Server Configuration Manager and make sure that the Named Pipes option is enabled for your Sql server instance.